# Display only dropdown Selected option rows in table

Tags: php, mysql

values of  drop down box are fetched from **database** in table header. when a user selects one of the option [ example : Undelivered ] in the drop down menu, then i need to display only the rows which have value "**Undelivered**"....

[image]

To Fetch value from Database : [ working fine ]

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT in_transit FROM do_order";
$result = mysqli_query ($mysqli, $sql);

echo '<select id="my_select" onchange="send_option();">'; 
echo '<option selected>Status</option>';

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) )
{
  echo "<option value='" . $row['in_transit'] . "'>" . $row['in_transit'] . "</option>";
}

echo '</select>';
```

Below code To display selected option rows [  display only Undelivered when user select Undelivered] : Not working

```
$in_transit = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['in_transit']);

        $sql1 = "SELECT in_transit FROM do_order WHERE in_transit LIKE '%$in_transit%'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
                {
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
                        {
                            echo "$row['in_transit']";                             
                        }
                }
```

Comment: Try adding a GROUP BY, if that's what the question is about and possibly a WHERE clause.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner i tried `$sql1 = "SELECT in_transit FROM do_order WHERE GROUP BY 'in_transit'";` , still it did't worked for me....

Comment: that isn't the proper syntax. Basic is `SELECT col(s) FROM table WHERE col_x = ? GROUP BY col_y`

Comment: `$in_transit = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['in_transit']);` what is this line please check the post value is correct?

Comment: Yes Of course you are not passing your select box value. Change your line like this`<select id="my_select" onchange="send_option();" name="in_transit">`

Comment: @Nawin updated code as you mentioned , but still page display like this : http://prntscr.com/iohuhf

Comment: That Error is in your PHP Error Please double check the Syntax and `;` and etc., or enable the error reporting using `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: i checked everything related to syntax, but it gave same issue.....

Comment: @Nawin Thanks for support....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
if(isset($_POST['in_transit'])){

echo $_POST['in_transit'];

 $sql1 = "SELECT in_transit FROM do_order WHERE in_transit LIKE '%$in_transit%'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
                {
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
                        {
                            echo "$row['in_transit']";                             
                        }
                }
}
```

ECHO the `$_POST['in_transit']` to be sure you're getting the Post Value before running the query. You can comment it if you're getting it the Post Value.